# How to include SimpleAudioEngine to Linux build in cocos2d-x v3.3 project?

Tags: linux, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying use SimpleAudioEngine in my project. I include the SimpleAudiEngine header to AppDelegate.

```
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

When I build my project for Android everything compiles and build is fine. SimpleAudioEngine working is correct.
If run build for Linux, I get an error message:

```
    fatal error: SimpleAudioEngine.h: No such file or directory
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

I tried include SimpleAudioEngine to CMake file - result remains the previous.

Comment: You may need to add manually the header to the include path so it can find the file. I had some simmilar issue on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this line of code to CMakeLists.txt (in cocos2D version 3.4 project):

${COCOS2D_ROOT}/cocos/audio/include

So CMakeLists.txt is somthing like this now:

```
...

include_directories(

    /usr/local/include/GLFW

    ...

    ${COCOS2D_ROOT}/cocos/audio/include

)
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. Build completed is successful.